# Sencha touch chart - How to some text below a pie chart

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-charts

I am using Sencha Touch charts 1.0.0 in my project. I created a pie chart with legend on RHS.
I would like to add some text below the chart. It is the total units represented by the chart and reads: "213 million units".

How can I add this? if not possible via charts, can it be added in as HTML element in the chart panel ?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

i guess it wont be possible by charts.

Try to create one parent panel , and Create pie chart in another panel and in one more panel create one HTML Div tag to show your required output.

Now add the two individual panels to Parent panel with `layout :'vbox'`

Or else  you can try with the div in the toolbar where toolbar docked bottom